# Change the fill color for multiple tags using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-developer-toolbar

```
<rect class="day" fill="#fbedf0" data-count="0"></rect>
<rect class="day" fill="#cqe45b" data-count="0"></rect>
```

I'm trying to edit the values of the fill color for multiple  tags using jQuery.

I'm able to iterate through all the rect tags and get their fill values, but am not able to change them using the css() function, and gives an error saying that the read css property of null

```
for(let i=0; i<rect.length; i++){
  if(rect[i].getAttribute("fill") === "cqe45b"){
    $('rect[i]').css({fill:"#2038fb"});
  }
}
```

What I essentially need is that, if the fill color is *#cqe45b*, I want to change it to *#2038fb* and if it were *#cbedf0*, I want to make it *#c7ef80*

**UPDATE:**
**I'm trying to perform this function on a third-party website which doesn't allow the import of jQuery, so, is there any way to go around this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all `rect.day[fill="#cqe45b"]` elements, and use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set the `fill` attribute's value.

```js
$('rect.day[fill="#cqe45b"]').attr("fill", "#2038fb");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg viewBox="0 0 300 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- Simple rect element -->
  <rect class="day" fill="#fbedf0" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" />

  <!-- Rounded corner rect element -->
  <rect  class="day" fill="#cqe45b" x="120" y="0" width="50" height="50" rx="15" ry="15" />
</svg>
```

And you can replace jQuery with [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), and [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

**Note:** [`NodeList.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) is not supported by IE. You can replace it for a for loop if you need to support IE.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('rect.day[fill="#cqe45b"]')
  .forEach((el) => {
    el.setAttribute("fill", "#2038fb")
  });
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- Simple rect element -->
  <rect class="day" fill="#fbedf0" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" />

  <!-- Rounded corner rect element -->
  <rect  class="day" fill="#cqe45b" x="120" y="0" width="50" height="50" rx="15" ry="15" />
</svg>
```

Comment: You don't need the each.  `attr()`, like most jQuery operators, performs an implicit each

Comment: @Taplar - I'm a bit jQuery rusty, but instead of filtering, it's better to just get the element by the fill attribute.

Comment: that's actually debatable.  If you can make your selector reflect a basic selector of class/tag/id, rather than an attribute selector, it can be optimized better.  And a filter does not involve a DOM lookup.  So a basic lookup paired with a filter can be faster.

Comment: I tried it, and it says that: 
`$(...).each` isn't a function

Comment: @Taplar - now days, it would be a premature optimization to use `.filter()` instead of a specific selector. Good call on dropping the `.each()`.

Comment: @RamPrash - I've updated the demo, and as you can see it's working. Try again.

Comment: I'd agree it could be pre-mature, however I would suggest getting into the habit can be worth while, but that's an opinion.

Comment: I think I figured why it might not be working for me. I'm using that code in the DOM directly (trying to perform this function on one of the pages i know). So I don't think it has jQuery imported in that page. 
So, how do I go around importing jQuery into a third-party page?

Comment: @RamPrash - I've added a solution that doesn't need jQuery.

Comment: Thanks a ton! @Ori

Answer (score 0):

In order to change an arbitrary attribute of a DOM element you want to use `.attr`. http://api.jquery.com/attr/

`$(rect[i]).attr("fill", "#2038fb");` should work.

You can achieve the `if... else` like this:

```
let newFill
switch (rect[i].getAttribute("fill")) {
  case "#cqe45b":
    newFill = "#2038fb"
    break
  case "cbedf0":
   newFill = "#c7ef80"
   break
  default:
    ???
}
$(rect[i]).attr("fill", newFill);
```

Comment: Whoops. I just copied and pasted from the example.
`$(rect[i]).attr("fill", newFill);`

Answer (score -1):

fill is an attribute, that's why it is not changing on .css method. Try this:

```
for(let i=0; i<rect.length; i++){
  if(rect[i].getAttribute("fill") === "#cqe45b"){
    $(this).attr("fill","#2038fb");
  }
}
```

Comment: Also instead of trying to use `attr()`, just use `setAttribute()`.  `$('rect[i]')` is not a valid css selector for the object

Comment: I get an error saying: 
`Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null`

PS: I used `#` while doing the comparison

Comment: `rect[i].setAttribute('fill', '#2038fb');`

Comment: try my script once

Comment: Your selector is still invalid @SantuRoy  That's not a valid css selector.  Otherwise remove the single quotes around it

Comment: There is no context change for a for loop